# Continuity of set inclusion function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $\cdots$ be a sequence of nonempty subsets of $[0,1]$. For $x \in [0,1]$, set $a_i (x) = 1$ if $x\in A_i$ and $0$ otherwise.

Define $f(x) = (0.a_1 (x) a_2 (x) a_3 (x) \cdots )_2$. That is, the sequence $\{a_i (x)\}$ concatenated and interpreted as a binary number.

Can we choose the sequence $\{A_i\}$ such that $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is continuous? Such that $f$ is differentiable?

For instance, we can take $A_i = [0,1]$ for every $i$. Then $f(x) = (0.1111\cdots)_2 = 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. What about nonconstant examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be arbitrary. Fix binary representations of every $x \in [0,1]$, in particular representing $1$ by $0.111\dots$ and $0$ by $0.000\dots$ . Define $b_i: [0,1] \to \{0 ,1\}$ to be the map that takes a number to the $i^\text{th}$ digit of the binary representation. Let $A_i = f^{-1}(b_i^{-1}(1))$.Then the function defined above is precisely $f$. Note also that the sets $b_i^{-1}$ are fairly "nice" (union of half open, open, and closed intervals) so for nice $f$ the sets $A_i$ shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

How about letting A_i be the set of reals whose binary expansion has a 1 in the i-th place (maybe union with {1}). So A_1 = [1/2,1], A_2 = [1/4,1/2) U [3/4, 1], etc. Then f ought to be the identity function.